# What is the flowing current through an inductor when the switching gets delayed?

Tags: circuit-analysis

Consider the following circuit in which the switching takes place instantaneously at \$t=0\$.

[image]

The current flowing through the inductor right before switching is \$ \tfrac{E}{R_1} \$.  As the current must be continuous then it must be the same right after switching. It is not hard to derive that $$ i_L(t)= \frac{E}{R_1}  \exp \left( -\frac{R_2}{L}t \right) $$ .

## Question

I wonder if there is an amount of time delay in switching, what is the current through the inductor? Does it become zero? Where does the stored energy in the inductor go?

Comment: *MathJax LaTeX renderer is not available here* - \$ \color{red}{\text{oh}}\color{blue}{\text{ yes}}\color{green}{\text{ it}}\color{orange}{\text{ is}}\$

Comment: Use "\ $" and not "$" as per \$t=0\$ but don't put a space between \ and $. You can still use $$ of course.

Comment: @Andy, use the code backticks in the comments to quote stuff: `\$`, etc.

Comment: @Transistor ahhh I think I might have known that (once) but forgot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I wonder if there is an amount of time delay in switching, what is the
>   current through the inductor? Does it become zero? Where does the
>   stored energy in the inductor go?*

It will instantly produce a spark across the open contact and fizzle the energy to zero pretty much in micro or nano seconds. The inductor does only what it knows as per this formula: -

$$V = L\dfrac{di}{dt}$$

Meaning that the rapid change in current causes a massive voltage and the energy burns off in the resulting spark.

Comment: Think about the equation Andy showed.  What happens to V, regardless of the value of L, as dt approaches zero?

Comment: If the time needed for the moving part of the switch to open the left circuit and to close the right circuit is long enough, does it mean that the inductor current has been  zero when the right circuit is closed?

Comment: If the time is long enough yes; there may be no energy left in the inductor to cause any current in the right-hand circuit.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about how **ideal** inductors in **ideal** circuits, then the scenario you describe is an invalid circuit. By this I mean that you have violated our definition of how an ideal circuit behaves such that the normal methods of analysis (KCL, KVL, etc.) no longer apply.

If the current through the inductor instantaneously changes from a non-zero value to zero then \$dV/dt\$ is mathematically undefined (it goes to infinity in the limit). So, all of our mathematical analysis goes out the window at that point.